# Array to javascript string

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

So I have this string:

`[{values: {"US" : "rgba(29, 79, 207, 1)"}},{values: {"NL" : "rgba(29, 79, 207, 1)"}}]`
This string sets colours for jvectormap. the entire reason for this function, I will only show countries that visited.

It's from Javascript, and I need to use this same format but in PHP and I think it has something to do with json encode but I can't get it to work.. So what I want to do is make an array into this string.. How would I do that?

When I make an array in PHP and encode it to json, this comes out: 
`[["NL","black"],["US","blue"]]` and this format wont work of course.

Comment: `json_decode($string);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've supplied invalid JSON. `values` needs to be quoted to become `"values"`, for PHP to decode it.

```
<?php

$string = <<<JSON
[{"values": {"US" : "rgba(29, 79, 207, 1)"}},{"values": {"NL" : "rgba(29, 79, 207, 1)"}}]
JSON;

echo print_r( json_decode($string, true), true);
```

https://eval.in/199639

An excellent JSON checker is http://json.parser.online.fr

You'd then create your array like;

```
$array = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'values' => 
    array (
      'US' => 'rgba(29, 79, 207, 1)',
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'values' => 
    array (
      'NL' => 'rgba(29, 79, 207, 1)',
    ),
  ),
);
echo json_encode($array);
```

https://eval.in/199684

Comment: I don't want PHP to decode it, I want to generate javascript code in the format that I posted by using an array (php).

Comment: Yes and that's exactly what my question is.

Comment: If I need to generate it like that I'd be better off making a pattern for the string. There must be an easier way so it can be done within a loop..

Comment: Sorry, now I'm confused. You want the array structure, but create it within a loop?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62112/discussion-between-user2879055-and-).